# Is there a way to see if an Nmap scan in the background is progressing?

Tags: nmap

I have launched an Nmap scan from an Ubuntu machine with the following parameters:

```
nmap -Pn -T3 -sS -sV -iL /home/tsouser/Desktop/Scope.txt --reason --top-ports 100 --max_rtt_timeout 200ms --initial_rtt_timeout 150ms --max_retries 3 -n -oA /home/user/Desktop/Test_nMap . &
```

As you may see, I am running the process in the background, and I would like to see if the scan is progressing or not. Is there a way to find out, without restarting the scan?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, get the process to the foreground:

```
$ fg
```

Then, you can use [these keys](https://nmap.org/book/man-runtime-interaction.html):

- v - Increase / decrease the verbosity level
- d - Increase / decrease the debugging Level
- p - Turn on / off packet tracing
- ? - Print a runtime interaction help screen
- Anything else - Print out a status message like this:

> ```
> Stats: 0:00:07 elapsed; 20 hosts completed (1 up), 1 undergoing Service Scan
> Service scan Timing: About 33.33% done; ETC: 20:57 (0:00:12 remaining)
> ```

Edit: then to get the process in the background again:

- hit Ctrl-Z to pause the process
- enter `bg` to run the process in the background.

You can use `jobs` to view the currently running processes.

Comment: Hello Sjoerd, thanks for your answer. I am connecting to the machine through SSH and it seems that once the session is closed, no active jobs are shown. Is there another method?

Comment: I figured it out. It seems that nMap writes the output to the file not once it's done scanning the whole scope, but it's incremental. So the command `tail` on the output file works just as well. Awarded to you since it's the most helpful answer, thanks again

Comment: [This edit was rejected](https://security.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/165856). One reviewer clearly hit reject without understanding what they were looking at, the other idk. Mentioning how to decrease verbosity is obviously helpful and the slash separator matches the increase/decrease wording that is used on each line so it's not confusing either. Sjoerd, do you want to include the changes?

Answer (score 1):

I found this out by accident but, in Bash, if you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>t</kbd> nmap will show you its current status.  And if you do this twice you'll see that the % complete will have changed

```
Stats: 0:13:52 elapsed; 0 hosts completed (1 up), 1 undergoing Connect Scan
Connect Scan Timing: About 23.82% done; ETC: 05:51 (0:44:22 remaining)
```

Comment: That's not the purpose of Ctrl+t. It just happened to work in your context.

Comment: If Ctrl+t  is because of "GNU Emacs, which uses control-T for transposing characters:" why did it work at all.  Was it because it caused some kind of interrupt?

Answer (score 1):

Another option that you have, in Linux, in case you can not put the process on foreground is to trace the process via **strace** and see what is doing, also if you use the **lsof** command you can see what are the sockets open for that process, but bear in mind that sometimes nmap works in promiscuous mode and you will see only a raw socket on the descriptors.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ps -aux`, nmap should appear as a running process.

- a = show processes for all users
- u = display user/owner
- x = include processes that are not attached to a terminal

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It would only indicate whether or not the process is still running, not whether any progress is made.